# Base section height based on element outside container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a website build with Bootstrap, with a section which contains some text in a `.img-content-description` div, which is inside the Bootstrap `.container` class. On the left, I have an image which is an external element outside the `.container`, so that it's filling the entire left half of the screen.

[image: Link for a visual example]

```css
.image-content {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.image-content .full-width-img {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-content .img-content-description {
  width: 40%;
}

.image-content .container-fluid {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.1.x library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- HTML -->
<section class="col-xs-12 image-content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="img-content-description smallerpadding">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Description</p>
          <a>Link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800.jpg" class="img-responsive full-width-img" />
</section>
```

Because of this structure, the sections height is based on the height of the div containing everything on the right side of the section. However, I want the image to fill the entire width of the left side (as it does currently), and determine the section's height based on the image height. I know all the images that will be used are 1920*1080px, but I don't know how to use this information to make this section responsive for all screen sizes. Below the stripped down version of the HTML:

Any help on how to achieve this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. In your example code, the image does not "fill the entire width of the left side". It's not even on the left side. Can you please share the code that you are using? I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind? This way, the height of the section will adapt to the tallest of its children.

```css
.image-content {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  overflow: hidden; /* make it cover (height) its content */
  width: 100%; /* set a width so that children can use a percentage of it */
}

.image-content > * {
  float: left;
}

.image-content .full-width-img {
  width: 50%;
/*
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
*/
}

.image-content > .container {
  margin-right: 8%; /* center it in its half of the section */
  margin-left: 8%; /* center it in its half of the section */
  width: 34%; /* override the .container's 100% width */
}

.image-content .container-fluid {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.1.x library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- HTML -->
<section class="col-xs-12 image-content">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800.jpg" class="img-responsive full-width-img" />

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="img-content-description smallerpadding">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Description</p>
          <a>Link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Seems like a promising solution, I'll try it when I get back home!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.full-width-img {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img-content-description {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- HTML -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="img-content-description smallerpadding">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Description</p>
      <a>Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800.jpg" class="img-responsive full-width-img" />
  </div>
</div>
```